# How to control vote count for individual user?

Tags: support, questions

How do I find if user has already voted for a particular question/answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way of finding this information out.

This has been discussed before and it would be a serious privacy breach if this information was made available.

Comment: Hence, we shall never never find out the question for which Eric Lippert cast his only upvote.

Comment: Right. you don't :P